# Uncaught TypeError: hook.apply is not a function on using onEnter in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Below is the code snippet:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, transition, callback) {
  console.log('hey');

  callback();
}


export const AdminList = {
  'path': 'admin-area/admin-list',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('components/admin/admin-list/admin-list').default);
    }, 'admin-list');
  },
  'onEnter': {requireAuth}
};
```

On entering the path `/admin-area/admin-list`, I get the error mentioned in the title from the file **TransitionUtils.js**.

I am not sure what is causing this error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is React Router failing to tell you that `onEnter` needs to be a function (you are currently wrapping it in an object).

To fix this, just assign the function itself to `onEnter` property (btw, you don't need to wrap `onEnter` in quotes):

```
  onEnter: requireAuth
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've wrapped onEnter in quotes 'coz I have asked eslint to log an error if object property names are not within single quotes so that I never assign a keyword as property name. I know it's very rare that anyone would use a keyword as property name but I am just trying to keep my code clean as much as possible.

Comment: I think **onEnter should be a function** would have been a better error message, no?